# Testing python function with list of arguments for exceptions

Tags: python, testing

I know pretty nothing about testing so need your help.

Got a python function that is being changed from time to time.
Also there is a list of arguments that this function should handle with no exceptions.
So the question - how to make correct simple test for this.

I need something like

```
for arg in args:
    cmd = 'python script.py %s' % arg
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, 
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    if err:
        print arg
        print err
```

Is it OK to do it with such self-written script or are there any special modules for this?

Or what is the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the module `script.py` contains a function `main()` that gets called when you call `script.py` as a script, with the usual idiom

```
import sys

def main(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    return 42

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

In this case, you can simply import the function `main` and do the testing without all the subprocess hassle:

```
from script import main as testsubject

assert testsubject(1, 2, 3) == 42
```

If `script.py` isn't in the python search path, you might have to add it manually:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/folder/containing/script.py")

from script import main
```

There is a package called `unittest` as part of the standard library specifically for testing such functions, with a readable documentation, so I strongly suggest you give that a try.

With `uittest`, a test might look like this:

```
import unittest

import script

class Test_Script(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_return_value(self):
        answer = script.main(1, 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(answer, 42)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**Edited to add:**

If your function has no return value and all you want to know is whether your function throws an exception, your test function can be simply written as something like

```
    def test_runs_without_exception(self):
        script.main(1, 2, 3)
```

If `script.main()` throws an exception, then `unittest` will catch that exception and print an appropriate failure message.

If all you want to do is to simply test a single script, using `unittest` might be overkill, and you can get away with perhaps a simpler

```
import time

import script

try:
    sript.main(1, 2, 3)
except Exception as e:
    print("An Exception occured!")
    with open("script_log.txt", "a") as logfile:
        logfile.write(str(time.time()) + "\t" + str(e))
    raise e
else:
    print("Everything is fine.")
```

If you have control over `script.py`, you may want to include some logging facility in `script.py` directly. In this case, you may want to look into the package `logging`.

Comment: The problem is that my function returns nothing. It just prints tons of info. So i don't need to check equality; i want to be sure that there is no exceptions

Comment: Expanded the answer to include the case of a function with no return value.